# memory leaks in iOS (objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I am having a hard time trying to understand memory leaks in my project. Some of them are simple statements as:

```
-(void)configureNotificationTypesFor:(NSDictionary *)notificationDict
{
    NSArray *keys = [notificationDict allKeys]; // leaks 1 byte of memory
```

Another example is where I call a method:

```
[self updateNotificationCount:totalNotificationCount];  // This leaks 15 bytes of memory.
[self.tableView reloadData];   // This leaks 25 bytes of memory.
```

Honestly, I don't think that there is something wrong with the about code. Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly I don't know. First allocate the Array(Keys).NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initwithObjects:];

Comment: Some memory leaks we can't do anything. That time if application is not crashing then that time don't think about memory leaks.

Comment: @PhaniRaghu - Then app doesn't crash at all, it's just that I have been assigned to this task. FML.

Comment: Ok. for first one put the code in NSLog. NSLog("%@", [notificationDict allKeys]); Then you can know issue with array or not.

Comment: For second two lines of code run the code on main thread. My answers are my assumptions. Just try it.

Comment: How do you know for instance `[self.tableView reloadData];` leaks?

Comment: @shallowThought - I am using Instruments.

Comment: I thought so, but you might misinterpret Instruments output. I suspect `reload data` triggers the "leak maker", but it actually leaks somewhere else. For instance the code in `cellForRowAt...`.

Comment: @shallowThought - True that, I just read it somewhere that the cause is where cells are configured.

Comment: You have to learn how to read Instruments output. Maybe start [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started) and and learn the grafical memory debugger _afterwards_.

Comment: What is being leaked-- what kind of allocation-- and what is the backtrace of the leak?  Instruments can tell you both.